# Can a Docker instance be run on a system that doesn't have the Docker Engine installed?

Tags: docker

Trying to learn Docker and reading and re-reading [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/faq/) but not understanding.

From what I've understood, Docker containers are managed by the Docker Engine, which interfaces with the host system OS / kernel.

If I boot up a brand-new Windows system and attempt to start an image instance, does the Windows system already have the engine install? Or, is the engine part of the image?

Comment: No, Windows doesn't come with docker preinstalled.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. From the link I posted above: "The Docker platform runs natively on Linux (on x86-64, ARM and many other CPU architectures) and on Windows (x86-64)." Is this supposed to mean that the Docker images / containers can be run on any Windows or Linux system that has the Docker engine installed?

Comment: Yes. There are however Windows and Linux images, a linux system can only linux containers, Windows can in theory both, just not at the same time.